# Why も in 私も暇な時、犬といっしょに・・・

Tags: particles

Can somebody explain も here to me please? And why it is not の?

```
私も暇な時、犬といっしょに近所を散歩します
```

I know it is used to mean with or also (私もです - me too), but the above to me would be 私の暇な時 showing possession. Or is も meaning "when" somehow?

Comment: Show us the context before this sentence.
In the context, some hint is surely written that it is inevitable to use "も" in this sentence.

Comment: @Chocolate なんかの間違いちゃう？二つの質問の関連性がわからへんけど。

Comment: @l'électeur およ？ parsingが同じかな思て・・主語＋｛従属節｝＋主節、みたいな・・ごめん、消しますｗ

Answer (score 3):

Parse it this way:

> 私も｛暇な時、｝犬といっしょに近所を散歩します。

私 is the subject of the main clause 犬といっしょに近所を散歩します.
暇な時 is a subordinate clause.

"I also take a walk in my neighborhood with my dog {when I have free time}."

The も means "also/too", as in "I take a walk too, just as someone else does."